# Highcharts - margin top to yAxis label

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using at highcharts to show charts in my website, and I have a problem - 
I want to bold one label, but it move up because its font larger, see in the image: [image]

I format the label in this way -

```
labels: {
   formatter: function() {
      if (this.value == 4) {
              return (
                '<span style="font-size: 40px; font-weight:bold;">' +
                this.value +
                "</span>"
              );
            }
            return this.value;
          }
         }
```

How can I fix it?

Here is [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/s2avLxto/1/).

Comment: Please add a [MCVE].

Comment: @ewolden, I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by default in Highcharts, but
you can overwrite `getLabelPosition` method in `Tick` prototype and take into account different label sizes in the calculations:

```
if (!this.axis.isXAxis) {
    yOffset = -label.getBBox().y / 2;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wq93xtsr/

Comment: Thanks! You help me a lot!